# Chinese remainder theorem in a Dedekind domain.

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, chinese-remainder-theorem

I want to prove the following :
Let $a_1,...,a_n$ ideals and $x_1,...,x_n$ elements of a Dedekind domain $A$. Then the system of congruences $x \equiv x_i \pmod{a_i}$ for $i = 1,...,n$ has a solution $x \in A$ iff $x_i \equiv x_j \pmod{a_i + a_j}$ for all $i \neq j$.
This is my try :
$(\Rightarrow)$\
Let $x \in A$ solution of $x \equiv x_i  \pmod{a_i}$. So, for all $i \neq j$ : 
$$ x_i - x_j = (x-x_j) - (x - x_i) \in (a_i + a_j)$$
hence
$$ x_i \equiv x_j  \pmod{a_i + a_j}$$
$(\Leftarrow)$\
Assume $x_i \equiv x_j  \pmod{a_i + a_j}$. Let
$$ \phi : A \rightarrow A/a_1 \oplus ... \oplus A/a_n$$
defined by $\phi(x) = (x + a_1,...,x+a_n)$. 
If I show that $\phi$ is surjective, then consider $x_1,...,x_n \in A$ and $(x_1+a_1,...,x_n +a_n) \in A/a_1 \oplus ... \oplus A/a_n$. Since $\phi$ is surjective, there exists $x \in A$ such that $$\phi(x) = (x_1 + a_1,...,x_n+a_n)$$
i.e. $x \equiv x_i  \pmod{a_i}$ for each $i=1,...,n$. 
There remains to show that $\phi$ is surjective.
$\phi$ is surjective iff for all ideals $p \neq 0$ of $A$, $\phi_p$ ( the localization of $\phi$ under $p$) is surjective. $A$ is a Dedekind domain hence its localization is a DVR. Assume $A$ is a DVR and show that $\phi$ is surjective. 
Let $m$ the maximal ideal of $A$ hence :
$a_i = m^{s_i}$
for $s_i \in \mathbb{N}$.
WLOG:
$$s_1 \leq s_2 \leq ... \leq s_n$$
hence for all  $i < j$
$$ x_i - x_j \in a_i + a_j = m^{s_i} + m^{s_j} \subseteq m^{s_i}$$
i.e. $x_i \equiv x_j  \pmod{a_i}$.
In particular 
$$x_n \equiv x_i  \pmod{a_i}$$ 
for all $i = 1,...,n$.   Hence
$$\phi(x_n) = (x_1 + a_1,...,x_n+a_n)$$
i.e. $\phi$ is surjective.
Is my proof correct?

Comment: Conceptually, try to prove a more general theorem with arbitrary nonzero ideals $\mathfrak a_i$ in place of your principal ideals $(a_i)$.  Also, before you try to tackle the case of arbitrary Dedekind domains, do you know how to prove your result when $A = \mathbf Z$?  And then can you prove the result for general Dedekind domains $A$ in the special case that the ideals $\mathfrak a_i$ are pairwise coprime: $\mathfrak a_i + \mathfrak a_j = (1)$ for $i \not= j$.

Comment: In the proof I didn't assume that the $a_i$ are principal ideals; Is my proof wrong? Another question :  the condition $a_i + a_j = (1)$ for $i \neq j$ is somehow related to the condition $x_i \equiv x_j (mod a_i + a_j $) ?

Comment: For $\mathbb{Z}$ I know this version of the theorem : let $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $\mathbb{Z}_{mn} \cong \mathbb{Z}_m \oplus \mathbb{Z}_n$ iff $(m,n) = 1$. The iso is given by $[k]_{mn} \mapsto ([k]_m , [k]_n)$

Comment: Oh, sorry. I did not notice the exact wording at the start and was misled by the fonts ($a_i$ rather than $\mathfrak a_i$).

Comment: Wrong/unconventional fonts, i'm sorry! Anyway, is my proof correct?

Comment: Tell us which step(s) you are *not* confident in (surely not everything).

Comment: It seems strange to me the fact that the solution of the system of congruences can be found among the $x_i$'s.

Comment: You are dealing there with a *special case*, not the general case!  Look at that exact situation in the case of the integers with moduli that are powers of some common prime $p$.

Comment: Ok,so, this special case comes out when I localize the Dedekind domain $A$ and deal with a DVR, right?

Comment: Of course.  The entire purpose of these reduction steps is to put yourself in a situation where the task becomes easy.  So you should really review again *why* surjectivity of $\phi$ follows from surjectivity of $\phi_{\mathfrak p}$ for all nonzero prime ideals $\mathfrak p$. (LaTeX tip: use the mathfrak command to make a letter have Fraktur font, which looks more pleasing as an ideal than $p$ or $a_i$.)

Comment: I found that useful result  ($\phi$ surjective iff $\phi_\mathfrak{p}$ surjective for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p} \neq 0$)  and its proof in Atiyah-Macdonald's Introduction to Commutative Algebra ( Proposition 3.9 ). 
(Thanks for the LaTeX tip )

Comment: I first learned it there too. When I suggested reviewing why it works, I meant to review the proof so that one mystery (how a construction in the localized case can be so easy when the construction in the general case might not look so easy) gets shifted to another mystery (how surjectivity of all $\phi_{\mathfrak p}$ can imply surjectivity of $\phi$).  By the way, in these CRT problems it is simpler to prove directly not solvability of general congruences but only the special cases where one $x_i$ is 1 and all the rest are $0$ (the general case follows from this by $A$-linear combinations).

Comment: The special case where one of the $x_i$ is 1 and others are 0 is the case when the ideals $\mathfrak{a_i}$ are such that for $i \neq j$,  $\mathfrak{a}_i + \mathfrak{a}_j = (1)$ right?

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're right.  Anyway, *in practice* the case of coprime ideals is the most important one (and is valid in arbitrary commutative rings, not just Dedekind domains, and does not need a reduction to the local case).

Comment: Thank you, this discussion has been very useful to me.